# Run two co-simulation FMUs at a time step using the same states but different inputs

Tags: fmi

I am trying to run an FMU for a nominal input and at the same time step for a perturbed input using the same states as the original FMU.

The main difficulty here is making a copy of the FMU i.e. saving the numerical data and setting it again in an FMU.

At the moment, I have been working with fmpy and this package does have several functionalities for saving and setting the states. However, none of these are supported by the FMU that I am working with at the moment. So I would need to look if there is another way around this to access to numerical data.

Additionally, I tried the CancelStep functionality to try to reset the states of the FMU, but this provided an 'error 3' output.

```
from fmpy import *

from fmpy.fmi2 import FMU2Slave



fmu_filename = 'BouncingBall.fmu'



Ts = 0.01



# load fmu

model_description = read_model_description(fmu_filename)

vrs = {}

for variable in model_description.modelVariables:

    vrs[variable.name] = variable.valueReference



v = vrs['v']

y = vrs['h']



unzipdir = extract(fmu_filename)

fmu = FMU2Slave(guid=model_description.guid,

                unzipDirectory=unzipdir,

                modelIdentifier='BouncingBall',

                instanceName='instance1')



fmu.instantiate()

fmu.setupExperiment(startTime=0.)

fmu.enterInitializationMode()

fmu.exitInitializationMode()



v_t0 = 0

y_t0 = 2

dv = 0.1



fmu.setReal([v], [v_t0])

fmu.setReal([y], [y_t0])



fmu.doStep(currentCommunicationPoint=0., communicationStepSize=Ts)

print(fmu.getReal([y]))

print(fmu.getReal([v]))



fmu.cancelStep()



fmu.setReal([v], [v_t0 + dv])



fmu.doStep(currentCommunicationPoint=0., communicationStepSize=Ts)

print(fmu.getReal([y]))

print(fmu.getReal([v]))
```

Comment: Hm. It seems to me that you try to do the impossible.
I would suggest to use an exporting tool that allows for getting and setting states.
Or talk to the tool vendor that exports your current FMUs, if this feature can be realized.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have been working on this issue for a while and it seems that there indeed are no options to do this with the FMUs that I am currently working with.

But the part that I struggle with; as these FMUs are solved, the numerical data has to be stored somewhere. Even if it is not stored as a variable, there must be some memory allocation for storing this data. So why can this not be accessed?